# LEFT Join on a Subquery with specific criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables that I am trying to JOIN

```
table1
----------------------------
Id         Name         Num
123X       Apple        17

table2
-------------------------------------------------
id           EndDt         SomeVal      
123X         10/1/2021     xxx
123X         3/1/2022      yyy
```

I am attempting to Select from `table1 a` and `LEFT JOIN table2 b on a.id = b.id` - however, I want to only select on the id in table2 where `MAX(EndDt)`

```
Select a.*, b.SomeVal
from table1 a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b on a.id=b.id // and b.MAX(EndDt)
```

Is something like that doable?

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. I make some assumptions on your data though.

1. Use a `LEFT JOIN` with a subquery:

   ```sql
   SELECT T1.*,
          sq.SomeVal
   FROM dbo.Table1 T1
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.Id ORDER BY t2.EndDt DESC) AS RN,
                          t2.Id,
                          t2.SomeVal
                   FROM dbo.Table2 T2) sq ON T1.Id = T2.Id
                                         AND T2.RN = 1;
   ```
2. Use `APPLY` and `TOP`:

   ```sql
   SELECT T1.*,
          sq.SomeVal
   FROM dbo.Table1 T1
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1)
                            t2.Id,
                            t2.SomeVal
                     FROM dbo.Table2 T2
                     WHERE T2.Id = T1.Id
                     ORDER BY T2.EndDt DESC) sq;
   ```
3. Use a CTE and get the "top 1" row per group:

   ```sql
   WITH CTE AS(
       SELECT T1.*,
              T2.SomeVal,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ID ORDER BY T2.MaxDt DESC) AS RN
       FROM dbo.Table1 T1
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id)
   SELECT *
   FROM CT
   WHERE RN = 1;
   ```
4. Use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`:

   ```sql
   SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
          T1.*,
          T2.SomeVal
   FROM dbo.Table1 T1
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id
   ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ID ORDER BY T2.MaxDt DESC) ASC;
   ```

Note that options 3 and 4 won't work as expected if `ID` is not unique in the table `Table1` (hence my assumptions about your data).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the windowed ROW_NUMBER function to take the max `table2` first, and then join into that subquery.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, [Row] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.Id ORDER BY b.EndDt DESC)
    FROM table2 b
)
SELECT a.*, cte.SomeVal
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN cte ON a.id = cte.id AND cte.[Row] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single value, use a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    a.num,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 SomeValue 
        FROM table2 As b 
        WHERE b.id = a.id 
        ORDER BY b.EndDt DESC
    ) As SomeVal
FROM
    table1 a
```